# wordpress title and category as result

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

Pls have a look a the code below !Its from a wordpress plugin. 
How can i get the result
$search =  post title (space ) category name

```
    // Relation: Post title.
if( $relation === 'posttitle' ) {

  global $post;

  $search     = ( isset( $post->post_title ) ) ? $post->post_title : '';

}
```

Its from a wordpress plugin related-youtube-videos. I want to display you tube base on title and category !
This plugin has no option for both !

https://wordpress.org/plugins/related-youtube-videos/

related-youtube-videos\lib\RelatedYouTubeVideos\API.php

Many Thanks in Advance !

Comment: better ask on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can get category name using `get_the_category()` function

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$search = ( isset( $post->post_title ) ) ? $post->post_title . ' ' . $category[0]->cat_name : '';
```

Comment: But how do i merger both title and category name so that i get the value  title - category   for $search

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your requirement. Hope this helps